# C# timer and network call in parallel

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, parallel.foreach

I would like to have a `Timer` run for 5 seconds and simultaneously start a network request to a backend. I would like to then wait for both the timer and the request to complete before doing an action.

```
private async void doWork()
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    await doPostRequest();
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

Something like the above code, except have both of those tasks executing in parallel. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Task.WhenAll` for that:

```
private async void doWork()
{
    await Task.WhenAll(
      Task.Delay(5000),
      doPostRequest());
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

There is also `Task.WhenAny` that completes as soon as one of those is completed.

Is it intentional that you don't return a Task from this method? You cannot await `doWork` itself now.

Comment: Yes it is intentional. I don't need to get anything back out of  `doWork` in this scenario. Thanks!

Comment: @nassan: You should [avoid `async void`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) for several reasons. The appropriate return type for an asynchronous method that doesn't have a result is `Task`, not `void`.